# My fishing pole won't cast in terraria mobile

Tags: terraria-mobile

So I have worms and other bait but my pole won't cast i tried making a new one and even restarting my phone
But still it won't work please help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Part of this would require personal troubleshooting, I don't know how far you are but an uninstall would do the trick. I would suggest that you also report the incident to the developers (re-logic). The final option is you could just wait and hope that a patch/update that fixes your problem. I would have no other ideas beside those on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off you should make sure you have at least 75 tiles of water (a tile being as big as one block), then you should try using the right on-screen joystick, as that usually puts your bobber in front of you in the water, and if that doesn't work try tapping randomly on the screen which usually puts your bobber pretty far out, and if that doesn't work i don't know what will. To reduce the amount of junk fished, you need 200 tiles of water.